# System boots with brightness level set to the lowest setting

Tags: lightdm

After selecting the OS to load with grub, 12.04 boots to a dark screen. It seems a minor problem, because I only have to press the brightening key on may keyboard to cast some light. But every single time I reboot, the dark screen returns. is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

[This is a known bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-greeter/+bug/974260) If you have a Launchpad account, mark it as affecting you to increase its heat, and thereby its likelihood of attracting developer interest.

In the meantime, a possible workaround might be to use a display manager other than LightDM, since the bug appears to have appeared at the same time as LightDM became the default.

To instead use GNOME Display Manager (which used to be the default), run `sudo apt-get install gdm`. After the installation completes, a warning about having multiple display managers installed will appear, followed by a dialog asking which you want to use:
[image: Display manager warning]
[image: Display manager chooser]
Obviously, you should choose `gdm`.

To restore LightDM, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` to trigger the above dialog to reappear. This time, choose `lightdm` instead.